# Why does Windows Service not run my django server?

Tags: django-rest-framework, windows-services, pyinstaller

I try to create a windows service to run my django project server. I can start the service, however, the server didn't run. So I cannot find the server on the chrome browser. My code is below.
And my based-code from this website https://metallapan.se/post/windows-service-pywin32-pyinstaller/.
Does anyone know what am I missing to create a service to run my Django server? Thanks in advance.

```
import os
import time
import sys
import win32serviceutil  # ServiceFramework and commandline helper
import win32service  # Events
import servicemanager  # Simple setup and logging
# from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie

class TestServiceForMeasurewarning:
    """Silly little application stub"""

    def stop(self):
        """Stop the service"""
        self.running = False
    def run(self):
        """Main service loop. This is where work is done!"""

        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            def main():
                os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'django_tutorial.settings')
                try:
                    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
                except ImportError as exc:
                    raise ImportError(
                        "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                        "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                        "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
                    ) from exc
                # args = ['manage.py', 'runserver', '0.0.0.0:8002']
                args = ['manage.py', 'runserver', '0.0.0.0:8003']

                execute_from_command_line(args)
                # execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
            if __name__ == '__main__':
                main()


class MyServiceFramework(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = 'Test Service For Measurementwarning'
    _svc_display_name_ = 'MeasurementwarningTestingService'

    def SvcStop(self):
        """Stop the service"""
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        self.service_impl.stop()
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOPPED)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        """Start the service; does not return until stopped"""
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_START_PENDING)
        self.service_impl = TestServiceForMeasurewarning()
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
        # Run the service
        self.service_impl.run()


def init():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(MyServiceFramework)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(MyServiceFramework)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()
```

Answer (score 0):

When the service manager executes `SvcDoRun`, `__name__` will not be `'__main__'`, so just remove that if statement. You can actually remove the `main()` function and just put the code in the `service_impl` function directly.

Comment: Hi @Fredrik Håård . I tried your solution, but the server still can not find. Whether I need to do something like "runserver" even I turned my manage.py to a windows service ? Because normally we need to type in "manage.py runserver" in the command line to execute the django server.